# Redis store data efficiently(hashes)

Tags: redis, hashtable, collision-detection, hash-function, collision

I need some advice from your.  I am trying to store some data in very memory efficient way with redis and hashes(redis type). There are some lists of random strings(average size is 40 char, but max possible is 255 char in rfc) -- it is file id, for example we have 100kk file_id list.  Also we need track 2 params for each id: download_count(int, incremented) and server_id -- tiny int, 
redis config added with:

```
hash-max-ziplist-entries 1024
```

Firstly we reject store data as is(palin text), huge overhead:

```
file_id(40 byte) + download_count + server_id) * 100kk + redis pointers --no need to calculate at all.
```

Second, use some 128bit hash function and store as is with redis hash: but there is some overhead too, but less then in 1 one.

And finally we get something like this, with redis hash:

```
hmset(bucket, server_id_field, value1, download_count_filed, value2), 
server_id_field = crc32(file_id)
download_count_filed = crc32(file_id) + 1,
bucket = murmur2(file_id) div 10^5
```

So there are 100k buckets at all, so at this point we can get collision for example:(cataract collides with perit) thanks to [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed), and data get to same buckets, but there is crc32 hash for fields, and we theoretically can’t get collision at this point(less probability), could this scheme theoretically be collision resistance equal as for example 64 bit hash ?

But it is not really efficient memory scheme, so we could get something like this(with one filed):

```
hmset(bucket, crc32(file_id as server_id_and_download_count_field), value1+’--’+value2)
```

So we can’t use increment function, but we reduce fields and memory usage, and need some cpu to parse result and update it back with new values(incremented download_count), maybe we could use lua to make some built-in manipulation with this ?

**So my question**: 
Is it strong collision resistance(for 100kk data) or maybe we need to use some 64 bit hash function in fields(not crc32), but what about when we will have 1 billion rows is strong enough for this data ?

Maybe there is more efficient scheme ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Redis hash is a really nice fit for this. Looking at the [Redis doc for HSET](http://redis.io/commands/hset) we see

```
HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
```

We should also remember that Redis is all about strings. I sugest you split the `file_id` after X characters (say 10) and use the first part as `myhash` and the rest as `field1`. This way you collapse all file_ids starting with the same X chars into one hash and only pay for that once. So test with different length on your `myhash` and see what value is good for you.

Second thing to do is to create the `"Hello"`, your value. Since Redis likes strings you should encode all your data into one. Start with `server_id` since you know the size of this in bytes and then append `download_count`. If you're in Python you could easily use `struct.pack()` to get this into a string.

You could also see if all characters are present in your file_ids. If those are only a subset you could encode those as well into a much denser form and maybe save a few chars.

Good luck!